# symfony 4 dynamic route with array

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm quiet new to symfony and spend hours trying to find a solution.
I'm building a multilingual website where page slugs are differents. 
For example :

www.mywebsite.com/products EN will be www.mywebsite.com/produits FR but both use the same controller

I have to build a dynamic route and here is the way I did I'm pretty sure I can do better, could you help me?

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class websiteController{

    public function __construct(){

        $this -> route = array(
            'about' => 'page_about',
            'contact' => 'page_contact',
        );

    }

     /**
     * @Route("/{page}", name="page")
     */
    public function pageAction($page)
    {

        if($page == $this -> route['about']){
            return new Response('<html><body>page about</body></html>');
        }

        if($page == $this -> route['contact']){
            return new Response('<html><body>page contact</body></html>');
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a bundle for routing internationalization called [BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle) but it is **not** available for symfony 4 right now.

---

## Core symfony implementation

With core symfony you could use multiple routes for each controller, that would have a `{_locale}` parameter with default value, here the problem would be that two different URLs would be returning the same page.

e.g **/test** would be the same as **/test/en**

This might cause problems with SEO

here how the annotations would look like if you wish to implement this method

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{_locale}", defaults={"_locale"="en"}, requirements={"_locale":"en"}, name="default_en")
 * @Route("/δοκιμή/{_locale}", defaults={"_locale"="el"}, requirements={"_locale":"el"}, name="default_el", options = {"utf8": true})
 * @Route("/tester/{_locale}", defaults={"_locale"="fr"}, requirements={"_locale":"fr"}, name="default_fr")
 */
public function test($_locale)
{
    return new Response("Your current locale is : $_locale");
}
```

---

## Dynamic Route

Another option is to create a Routing Service that would apply your logic.
Here is an example.

this would be the controller that handles all the paths

#### Controller

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Service\Router;

class RouterController extends Controller {

    /**
    * @Route("/{path}", name="router", requirements={"path" = ".+"})
    */
    public function router($path,Request $request,Router $router) {

        $result=$router->handle($path);

        if($result){
            $result['args']['request']=$request;
            return $this->forward($result['class'], $result['args']);
        }


        throw $this->createNotFoundException('error page not found!');        
    }

}
```

This Controller Action depends on a service called **Router** so you will have to create a Router service that would return the an array (you can change it to return a custom object) with keys *class* and *args* that would be used to forward the request to a controller action.

#### Service

*/src/Service/Router.php*

Here you should implement a function called `handle` and you can apply any logic to it

here is a basic example

```
namespace App\Service;

class Router
{

    public function handle($path)
    {
        switch ($path) {
            case "test":
                return [
                    "class" => "App\Controller\TestController::index",
                    "args"  => [
                        "locale" => 'en'
                    ]
                ];
            case "tester":
                return [
                    "class" => "App\Controller\TestController::index",
                    "args"  => [
                        "locale" => 'fr'
                    ]
                ];
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above would forward the request to `TestController::index` function and will add as parameter to that function the `locale` variable and also it will include the `Request` object

You could store the routes in a yaml file or database or any other location you like. You can manipulate the `$path` variable to extract information about **id**, **page** etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm able to make it work at time.
I was thinking about a more human and conventional way to do that. Simply generate the .yaml file according to the slug the admin will define. Do you think it might be a good idea? In a way i'll be able to go on using some of the Yaml component features.

Comment: @raphaman I do not know if you still interested in that issue, but there were some news, in symfony 4.1 they will support route internationalization out of the box. You can take a look here http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-internationalized-routing